# How could I fill my second list with zero and one according to the conditions below?

Tags: python, list, random

I have a list containing multiple lists. It's full of random numbers between 0 and 1.
I need to create another list with the same size of the first one, but if the random numbers less or equal to 0.75, I need them equal to zero and the more than 0.75 will be one. When I need to print the second list x, it must contain zeros and ones according to my conditions below. I always get a list full of zeros, where is my fault?

This is below my try:

```
import random

y = [[random.uniform(0,1) for i in range(10)]for j in range(10)]
x = [[0 for i in range(len(y[0]))]for j in range(len(y))]

for i in range(len(y)):
    for j in range(len(y[0])):
        if y[i][j] <= 0.75:
            x[i][j] == 0
        else:
            x[i][j] == 1
print(x)
```

Comment: what isn't working?

Comment: @Sayse When I need to print x, It must be full of zeros and ones according to the conditions above.

Comment: Change `==` to `=`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your if/else code is wrong, you are using '==' instead '=' so x[i] value is not being updated. Try this:

```
import random

y = [[random.uniform(0,1) for i in range(10)]for j in range(10)]
x = [[0 for i in range(len(y[0]))]for j in range(len(y))]

for i in range(len(y)):
    for j in range(len(y[0])):
        if y[i][j] <= 0.75:
            x[i][j] = 0
        else:
            x[i][j] = 1
print(x)
```

Answer (score 3):

Put the condition in your list comprehension:

```
import random

y = [[random.uniform(0,1) for i in range(10)]for j in range(10)]
x = [[0 if val <=0.75 else 1 for val in sublist] for sublist in y]
print(x)
# [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can declare the way you want to act your condition then you can apply it against each element from your initial list:

```
import random
y = [[random.uniform(0,1) for i in range(10)]for j in range(10)]

cond = lambda x: int(x < 0.75)

x = list(map(lambda x : list(map(cond, x)), y))
```